# $25$ distinguishable balls be placed in two distinguishable boxes, where order/placing doesn't matter, only unique combinations accepted,…

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways can $25$ distinguishable balls be placed in two distinguishable boxes?

- Order/placing doesn't matter.
- Only unique combinations accepted (e.g., a blue ball whether placed in a box first or last would be considered the same).
- All balls must be selected.

Thank you for your input of wisdom.

Comment: Hint: Line up the balls in order of student number. First ball, how many choices of where to put it? For each of these choices, how many choices for the second ball? For every choice of location for the first two, how many for the third? Continue.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: I would like to wait a while, for you to use the hint and find the answer. If after a while you still have difficulty, please leave a message (ping).

Comment: would it be 625 unique arrangements? please the suspense is too much

Comment: I have spent hours on this!

Comment: The answer is not $625$, it is much larger. If there are $2$ balls instead of $25$, the answer is $4$. If there are $3$, the answer is $8$.  Another way of thinking you may have seen before. Let the boxes be A and B.  We will place into A a **subset** of the set of balls, the rest going into B. How many subsets does a set of $25$ objects have?

Comment: that would 25 subsets?

Comment: $2^{25}$ subsets.  Lots, more than $30$ million.

Comment: over 30 milllion just by putting 25 balls in two baskets? without repition? and order doesn't matter?

Comment: I had already strongly suggested the answer. For $2$ balls, $4$. For $3$ balls, $8$. For every way of deciding where the first $3$ balls go, there are $2$ ways to assign the fourth, for a total of $16$. And so on. You need to internalize this style of thinking, it will be needed often.

Comment: And yes, it is over $30$ million. You can get the exact number on your calculator.

Comment: But Andre what im trying to get out is unique arrangemets, example two combinations could be identical aprt from combination 1 the blue ball is in first position but in combination 2 its in fourth to me this is not a unique combination. if that makes sense?

Comment: Please do this for $n=3$ balls. Call them blue, white, red. Find all the ways to distribute them between boxes A and B. Just make a complete list of what could be in A. (i) Nothing (ii) Just blue (iii) Just white (iv) Just red (v) b and w (vi) b and r (vii) w and r (viii)) all. We had a result of $8$ ways. Now do it carefully for blue, white, red, yellow. You should get $16$. Doubles each time.

Comment: So is there anyway of bringing this figure of 30 Million considerably down?

Comment: Ok thankyou have a nice day

Comment: The large number $2^{25}$ is an instance of what is sometimes called *combinatorial explosion*. In many combinatorics problems, the number of possibilities grows very rapidly as the number of items ($25$ in this case) increases. More than a billion at $30$.

Comment: abcde & bcaed are the same im trying to elemenate repitions surly this figure of 30+million includes repitions?

Answer (score 1):

With most combinatorial problems, it helps to come up with a story of how the combination is constructed in time order.

For this situation, your story can go like this:
Take the first ball and decide which of the two boxes it will go in (2 options).
Take the second ball and decide which of the two boxes it will go in (2 options, which can go with either of the two options for ball 1, so that's $2 \times 2 = 4$ options so far).
Take the third ball and decide which of the two boxes it will go in (2 options, which can go with any of the options for ball 1 and 2 so that's $4 \times 2 = 8$ options).
Take the fourth ball and decide which of the two boxes it will go in (2 options, which can go with any of the options for balls 1, 2 and 3, so that's $8 \times 2 = 16$ options).

Continuing in this way we get a total number of options of $2 \times 2 \times \dots \times 2$ (25 2's multiplied together) $=2^{25}$.

---

You can convince yourself this is the right number by doing a different story:

Choose how many of the 25 balls will go into the first box. Let's say this number is $k$.
Now choose which exact collection of $k$ will go into the box. The number of ways to do this is ${25}\choose k$.
Since the options with each $k$ are distinct and don't overlap and don't go with each other, we add them up. So the total number of ways is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{25} {{25}\choose k}
$$
There is an identity that says when you add all these up you get $2^{25}$ (which you can prove by expanding out $(1+x)^{25}$ and subbing in $x=1$).